# How to install gsl 2.6 by using vcpkg?

Tags: windows, gsl, vcpkg

I am using `vcpkg` to install `gsl` on Windows. The `gsl`-version being installed is:

```
Source: gsl
Version: 2.4-5
Homepage: https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/
```

However, I need the functionalities of the latest version of `gsl`, i.e. 2.6.

Is there any possiblity to install `gsl 2.6` by using `vcpkg`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
vcpkg.exe x-history gsl
```

to see git commit ids which change the CONTROL file of the GSL port which can be used to checkout a specific version of GSL. The result for GSL is:

```
         version          date    vcpkg commit
           2.4-5    2020-01-06    2c7ff757a10a1d63e5fd6e295430f00bd67b902c
           2.4-4    2019-10-07    726c11148105a97aef39bec024fdb7c140b1b154
           2.4-3    2019-06-15    18b029a5e3997fa4fdc7d3d06d56568a1d6f74ad
           2.4-2    2017-09-09    26516fe485b0e9048dd4809256a7e4526957c6e9
           2.4-1    2017-07-25    8a6322e7f306a45594a0a75cb16174fd08cd87d1
           2.3-2    2017-07-21    e47238f98c3325d69e9731ab81d43b17a8372363
           2.3-1    2017-07-21    0c117ea3db646d2b1fe5979faf4f4c9c6e44b9f9
             2.3    2017-05-31    ed826d84124f52bc8625027ea672a3bd4e5d7d67
20170425-8b320e3f5d0    2017-05-03    bf483dde89c6ca509b8b32cad1e36b16de5ba10b
     0-fd5ad87bf    2016-10-26    42f180e5608322b180897bda1aeb877380e56ebb
```

as you can see 2.6 is not part of that history but
I added a PR to update the gsl port to 2.6
(see https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/pull/10758)

Feel free to merge that PR into your local clone of vcpkg or use the vcpkg --port-overlay feature. 
As soon as the PR is merged you can just `vcpkg.exe install gsl` to get the updated version.